# C++: Static pointers, static objects and dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c++, pointers, static-members, dynamic-memory-allocation

Consider the below code segment:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class p
{
    public:
    int* q;
    p()
    {
        q = new int(100);
    }
    ~p(){
        delete q;
    }
};

static p* p1 = new p();
static p p2;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    std::cout << *(p1->q);
    std::cout << *(p2.q);

    delete p1;
}
```

p1 and p2 are static vars, they have to stored in static segment.

1. since p1 is a pointer, is only the pointer address stored in static segment or even the object it points to?
2. p2 is a normal static object, but it contains a dynamically allocated member variable q,so is q also stored in static segment?

Comment: No, and no. More importantly, you shouldn't care.

Comment: why don't you run the code and see for yourself?

Comment: @CrakC this is generally not a good idea with C++.

Comment: @Quentin so you are telling me it's not a good idea to test one's own code and see what is happening before posting a question?

Comment: @CrakC It is, but once it is done the question should be asked anyway. C++ contains many instances of implementation-defined and undefined behaviour, which may well appear to work as expected when tested once on a particular machine.

Comment: Pointers are completely separate from the thing (if any) they are pointing to.  Struct members are part of a struct.

Comment: Note that the statement "p2 [...] contains a dynamically allocated member variable q" is incorrect. The variable `p::q` is a pointer containing the address of an int. That int has no name and is allocated on the heap. The member variable `p::q`, as part of an object of type `p`, is located wherever that object is located. In the case of the statically allocated object `p2`,  the part of `p2` which is named `p2.q` is also in statically allocated memory whose lifetime is that of the program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `p1` is a pointer, it's stored in static segment (I am not sure it's the right term), the object or memory `p1` points to is on heap.
2. `p2` is an object, it's stored in static segment. `q` is a pointer inside `p2`, the object or memory `q` points to is on heap.

Answer (score 2):

You have two objects which are *statically allocated*, a pointer named `p1` and an instance of type `p` named `p2`.

There are two places in your program where dynamic allocations can occur: in class `p`'s constructor and when the static variable `p1` is initialized.

The statically allocated objects `p1` (the pointer) and `p2` (the class instance) exist as long as the program runs. It is important to distinguish the pointer `p1` containing just an address from the class instance *at that address.* (That instance will be created at run time by `new p()`). The pointer and the "pointee" can have independent lifetimes; both exist independently from each other. The pointer may exist and not point to anything, and the object created by the `new p()` call may exist longer than any pointer to it.<sup>1</sup>

Here is the sequence of events which unfolds when your program starts. Initialization of static variables is specified in section 3.6.2 of the C++11 standard.

1. **Allocation of variables with *static storage duration*,** here `p1` and `p2`. A working model of that is that the memory is part of the program.
2. **Zeroing of those variables.** "Variables with static storage duration [...] shall be zero-initialized before any other initialization takes place." The pointer `p1` as well as the memory where `p2` resides now consist of bytes which are all zero.
3. **Dynamic (i.e. run-time) initialization of those variables** in the order of their definition:

   - Initialization of the pointer `p1` starts with calling `new p()`.

     - Memory for a new object of type `p` is allocated dynamically ("on the heap") with the standard allocator. The memory's contents is not initialized and unknown. The object doesn't have a name, so let's call it `x`.
     - `x`' constructor is executed in order to initialize it.

       - The constructor assigns a value to the hitherto uninitialized member variable `x.q`. `x.q` is part of `x` and as such resides in the memory dynamically allocated before.
       - The right hand side of the assignment is another call to `new`, this time for an int. The standard allocator dynamically allocates memory for an int which is initialized with 100.
       - The return value of `new` is the memory address where the int resides, which is assigned to the int pointer `x.q`.
     - `x`' constructor returns, and `new p()` returns the memory address where `x` resides.
     - This return value is assigned to hitherto zero-initialized `p1` which now points to the unnamed `p` instance we called `x`.
   - **Initialization of `p2`.** `p2`'s constructor is executed which does the same thing as `x`'s constructor above: It calls `new` for an int which causes a dynamic memory allocation, initializes it with 100 and assigns the address of the int's memory location to `p2.q`.

The result, as far as memory locations and the relations between objects are concerned, is shown in the diagram below.

[image: Memory schematics of your program]

This should help answer your questions:

1. `p1` is in the "static segment", if you want, but the object it points to has been dynamically allocated at run time by the call to `new`.
2. The static object `p2` **does not** contain "a dynamically allocated member variable q". That sentence confuses the member variable -- a pointer named `q` -- with the object *to which `q` points,* which is a dynamically allocated int. The member variable `q` is stored wherever the containing instance of class `p` is stored; in fact, it *is* the only data in that instance. (Try `sizeof(p)`!) The object to which any instance's member `q` points is always a dynamically allocated int (well, that is until some malevolent programmer assigns a different value to your public `q`).

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>That would constitute a memory leak because a dynamically allocated object whose address has been lost can never be deleted by the program.</sub>